# Volley does not resize the image properly

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-volley

I'm consuming a service from youtube where it returns me a URL. With this URL, I carry on a NetworkImageView. The issue is that the image does not take up all the space I define the field NetworkImageView

My URL

```
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2HA41DV_K7s/hqdefault.jpg
```

XML

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/banner_channel"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In my adapter

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Context ctx = parent.getContext();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(LAYOUT, null);
        }
        NetworkImageView img = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.banner_channel);


        img.setImageUrl(mVideoList.items.get(position).snippet.thumbnails.high.url, VolleySingleton.getInstance(
                ctx).getImageLoader());
        img.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.channel_thumb_default);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Class cache

```
/**
 * Created by Douglas on 24/08/2014.
 */
public class VolleySingleton {

    private static VolleySingleton mInstance = null;
    // Fila de execução
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    // Image Loader
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private VolleySingleton(Context context) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> mCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(10);

            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                mCache.put(url, bitmap);
            }

            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return mCache.get(url);
            }
        });
    }

    public static VolleySingleton getInstance(
            Context context) {

        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new VolleySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        return this.mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }
}
```

Image of my list

[image: http://i.imgur.com/gsEkt9R.png]

Comment: What are you expecting to see that isn't happening? That looks, to me, just like a 120x90 resizing of the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working properly. The letterboxing effect (black bars on the top and bottom) is part of the image you were fetching.

EDIT:

to create a bitmap with the original image but without the black bars, use

```
Bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

where

source - The original bitmap with black bars

x - The x coordinate of the first pixel in source

y - The y coordinate of the first pixel in source

width - The number of pixels in each row

height - The number of rows

Comment: there is the possibility I remove this black bar?

Comment: Sure you can. Analyze the image and check if the black bars in all images are consistent in size, then do some simple image cropping on the bitmap (see edit in my answer)